# Менять родительскую переменную в дочернем компоненте

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

В родительском компоненте есть переменная которая отвечает за состояние checkbox и нужно менять ее в дочернем компоненте при нажатии на checkbox, подскажите что я делаю неправильно и как можно это исправить?

```
РОДИТЕЛЬСКИЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ

<template>
  <div class="contact-form">
    <form @submit.prevent="sendMail">
      <div class="contact-form__actions">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        <CheckBoxInput
          model="mail.newsletterSub"
          id="contact-terms"
          :label="checkboxOptions.label"
          :dark="checkboxOptions.dark"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CheckBoxInput from "@/components/inputs/CheckBoxInput";

export default {
  name: "ContactUsForm",
  components: {
    CheckBoxInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      mail: {
        newsletterSub: false,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendMail(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      this.mail = {
        newsletterSub: false,
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
ДОЧЕРНИЙ CHECKBOX

<template>
  <div :class="[`checkbox-input`, `${dark ? 'checkbox-input_dark' : ''}`]">
    <input :id="id.replace(' ', '')" type="checkbox" v-model="model" />
    <label class="body-3" :for="id.replace(' ', '')">
      {{ label }}
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CheckBoxInput",
  props: {
    value: {},
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    dark: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("change", value);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для реализации такой логики вам необходимо обратиться к [разделу документации о работе с emit для настройки v-model](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-v-model-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0). Ниже пример использования данного подхода (может возникнуть вопрос о разнице между эвентами `change` и `input`, [тут данный хороший ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343859/whats-the-difference-between-input-and-change-in-vue-input-type-file)):

```js
const CheckBox = Vue.component("CheckBox", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="localValue"/>
        Checkbox
      </label>
    </div>
  `,
  model: {
    event: 'change',
    prop: 'value',
  },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    // Объявляем вычисляемое свойство с геттером и сеттером
    // чтобы не делать промежуточную локальную переменную и вотчер
    localValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.$emit('change', newValue);
      },
    },
  },
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    CheckBox,
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <CheckBox v-model='value'></CheckBox>
      Result: {{ value }}
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      value: true,
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Ответ основан на ответе участника [Дмытрык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/271553/%D0%94%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BA), данный выше и содержит некоторые правки для оптимизации кода и ознакомительную информацию.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const CheckBox = Vue.component("CheckBox", {
  template: `<div>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" v-model="value"></input>Checkbox</label>
  </div>`,
  props: {
    checkBox: {
      type: Boolean
    },
  },
  model: {
    event: "change",
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.checkBox,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value: function(e) {
      this.$emit("change", e);
    },
  },
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    CheckBox
  },
  template: `<CheckBox v-model='value' :checkBox="value"></CheckBox>`,
  data() {
    return {
      value: true,
    };
  },
  // для визуализации изменений в родительском компоненте
  watch: {
    value: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @МаксимВишневский не надо править чужой код до неузнаваемости. Есть желание сдалеть красивее - дайте свой ответ

Comment: У меня не было желания исправить код до неузнаваемости, я его немного оптимизировал и визуально поправил отступы, так же добавил ссылку на доку и описание, чтобы было более понятно что там происходит. Не нужно воспринимать в штыки. Если так будет удобнее, вынесу правку в отдельный ответ.

Comment: @МаксимВишневский, что в моем сообщении воспринялось Вами, как: `Не нужно воспринимать в штыки` ? Если опустить все доп. строки, которые Вы написали, опустить изменение порядка следования свойстви и параметров... а оставить только замену `watch` на `computed` с геттером и сеттером... то это абсолютно другой стиль, которым я не пользуюсь... Поэтому это уже не мой ответ...

Comment: Ок, я не буду с вами спорить, ваш подход правильный и не имеет никаких проблем, соглашусь, что моя правка стилистически другая, вынес в отдельный ответ =)